# Assignment of malloc'ed array to stack'ed array

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, heap-memory, stack-memory

I was trying to return an array from `child_prog()`  to `main()`. The code looks like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int* child_prog(int some_input);

void main(void){
  int C[10];
  int some_input;
  C = child_prog(some_input);
}

int* child_prog(int some_input){
  static int out[10];
  // ...
  // ... some wizardry
  return out;
}
```

Now the compiler generates an error saying that it can not assign to `C` (which is an `int[]` type) the value returned from `child_prog` (which is an `int*` type). Indeed, the program works fine when I make `C` an `int*` and `malloc` it 10 `ints` of memory. But I don't understand why the compiler can't assign to `C` (an array defined as `C[10]` and hence a pointer) the value returned from `child_prog` (an array defined as `static int out[10]` and hence again a pointer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You cannot assign to an array. You need to `memcpy` it.
2. `int*` != `int[]` while the first **is a pointer** that might point to an `int` of a sequence of `int`s, the second **is a sequence** of `int`s
3. You can use `int *C;` and pass the length of the array (if unknown at compile time) as an out parameter.
4. `static int out[10];` is not a `malloc`ed, but static.

Comment: Ok, understood point number-1 that int*!=int[]. But, in the case when I define C as int* C instead of int C[], and malloc it the known amount of memory, and child_prog returns to C the pointer to the static int array, shouldn't I be able to bypass the need to do memcpy?

Comment: If you are not assigning to an array, but to a pointer, you don't need `memcpy`.

Comment: Thanks for slaying a lot of my dragons ... rather quickly

Answer (score 1):

One solution can be to declare C as:

```
int *C;
```

as said by Binyamin
You cannot change the address of an array as it is statically allocated, which precisely you are trying to do with:

```
C = child_prog(some_input);
```

Answer (score 0):

- The type of `int []` is `int * const` which means the memory it points to is a constant and trying to change it will give a compiler error. Obviously it isn't equal to `int *`.
- The variable `out` in `child_prog()` is statically allocated which means its not on the stack but somewhere in the global data section. Hence no matter how many times you call `child_prog()`, you'll always be returned the same memory location.
- Hence to copy the array, do a `memcpy(dest,src,bytes)` if you want to save the data returned from `child_prog()`.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define SUCCESS    0 
#define FAILURE    1 

int child_prog(int some_input, int *output, int output_size);

void main(void){
  int C[10];
  int some_input;
  C = child_prog(some_input, c, 10);
}

int  child_prog(int some_input, int *output, int output_size)
{
  static int source[10];
      ...
      .../*some wizardry*/

  memcpy(output, source, output_size);


     ... if (erronous Condition)
             return FAILURE;
         else

  return SUCCESS;
}
```